# Can infinity be represented as a recursive function?

Tags: functions, infinity

Could infinity be represented as a recursive function like:

The function f takes any number x as parameter and returns f(x+1), resulting in an endless recursive call, each call incrementing x by 1. Logically, the answer of the initial function call would never be returned, but because in a theoretical sense, the calls would happen instantly, then could one say that f(x) = ∞, where f returns a call to itself with x+1? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concretely, you seem to be asking what function(s) satisfy the functional equation $f(x) = f(x+1)$. To make that question precise, you would need to specify the desired domain and range of the function $f$.  One choice you might have in mind is that $f$ should be defined on the positive integers and take on positive integer values.  In such a case, choose any value $n$ for $f(1)$.  Then by the functional equation, $f(2) = f(1) = n$, and $f(3) = f(2) = n$, and so on by induction, $f(m) = n$ for all positive integers $m$.  That is, $f$ will be a constant function, and so we have shown (for this particular domain and range) that the collection of all $f$ satisfying the given functional equation are all the constant functions.  You won't find $\infty$ as a value of any of these functions, simply because the range we considered did not contain any element "$\infty$". So to try to get at your larger question, no, I would not characterize this scheme as a method of "generating" infinity, whatever that might mean.

For anyone to be able to give a more specific answer to your initial question, you would need to specify more exactly what you might mean by the vague language of a function "representing" infinity?  Represent in what way?

Comment: Represnting in the sense of logical equivalence, as in f(x) ≡ ∞...I guess the essence of my question is if infinity could somehow be represented in some incremental way. The reasoning behind "representing" is that infinity could never be acheived by lets say repeated addition, in the same sense that 0 could not be achieved by 1/∞, as you would get infinitly close to 0, but never really 0... Infinity is in itself (at least to me) a vague concept... I guess an underlaying question is also if infinity could at all be a constant, since there exist no such thing as the largest number...

Comment: There are many different rigorous mathematical treatments of infinity, depending on what aspect of it you want to model.  The basic investigation into the nature of infinity lies in the realm of set theory, a branch of logic.  The intuitive concept of infinity you are describing seems, to me, to be closest to [ordinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic), and in particular to $\omega$, the first infinite ordinal.